# dd/mm/yyyy and day python without library at python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to write a program that asks for the user to input the date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and convert it. So, if the user input `05/10/2014`, the program should display Monday without using library at python ! )

```
d, m, y = raw_input("Enter a date: ").split('/')
```

Comment: Why *"without using datetime"*? What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: If you for whatever reason need to do it without any library then you need to work out an algorithm to calculate what you need.  Note that it is not simple as you have to deal with leap years etc. - hence why it makes sense to use a library that has already been written to handle all these cases.  Also note that you say you want to read mm/dd/yyy but split it into d,m,y with the order different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`calendar.weekday()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday); pass in a year, month and day (as integers) and it'll return the weekday as an integer (`0` is Monday, etc.):

```
import calendar

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
d, m, y = map(int, raw_input("Enter a date: ").split('/'))
weekday = calendar.weekday(y, m, d)
print days[weekday]
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.weekday(2016, 1, 14)
3
>>> days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
>>> days[calendar.weekday(2016, 1, 14)]
'Thursday'
```

Comment: and if  dont want to use any library at python

Comment: @B.Clow: why re-invent this wheel? The `calendar`, `datetime` and `time` are all part of the standard library. Your question did not specify anything about not using libraries, nor do you show any attempt to work this out yourself first.

Comment: @B.Clow: but basically, you'd end up re-implementing the same logic the [`datetime` module already implements, in C code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/datetimemodule.c). Reimplement the `is_leap`, `days_before_month `, `days_before_year`, `ymd_to_ord`, and `weekday` functions.

Comment: yea i know i just do a wrong ( it is my first question ) but  u help me   thank you !